# Can I keymap scrubbing the timeline with the mouse wheel?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, timeline

Title says it all. I want to be able to scrub the Video Sequencer or timeline with the mousewheel, preferably with a modifier key such as shift or alt. I want to program the firmware of a rotary encoder peripheral to do it.

Comment: Alt+mouse wheel should do what you want?

Comment: wow. thanks. idk what to say.

Answer (score 1):

I posted the answer to my question within my own question. Questception.

Alt+mousewheel scrubs the sequencer.